# Not able to install minix in virtualbox in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, minix

i am getting an error msz..!!

```
 No Bootable medium found. System halted
```

I have iso images of minix3 downloaded from [here](http://www.minix3.org/previous-versions/).
i downlaoded book version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done.. I just restarted my system.